# Sort top N maximum absolute values of a column per members using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

My current pandas dataframe is as follows:

[image]

I want to select top 2 maximum absolute values per IDs from the above pandas dataframe as below:

[image].

I tried with

```
df.sort_values(by='Values', key=abs,ascending=False)
```

But it didn't gave the desired output. I tried with

```
df.sort_values('Values',key=abs,ascending=False).groupby('ID')
```

as well. None of them worked to give me the above output. Moreover, I couldn't use the query function to filter Ids due to the use of groupby function.   I appreciate your suggestions . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `head`

```
out = df.sort_values('Values',key=abs,ascending=False).groupby('ID').head(2)
```

Comment: It will now allow me to filter IDs as df.query('row_id == 1001') to see it's top 2 Name  values.